# Schuller Quantum Theory Problem Sheets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education, specific-reference

Does anyone have the problem sheets from Schuller's lectures "Lectures on Quantum Theory"? Or does anyone know a way how to obtain them? I tried emailing Schuller, but no reply.